# React child component is not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component, say parent where I have these values

```
const [filterYear, setFilterYear] = useState<string>('');
const [filterFilingType, setFilterFilingType] = useState<string>('');
```

Then I have a button

```
    <Button
     onClick={showModal}
    >
     "create"
    </Button>
```

this is the function for modal

```
const showModal = () => {
    Modal.render({

      title: t('createFiling'),
      content: (
        <InlineGroup>
          <Inputs.Select
            placeholder={t('selectFilingYear')}
            list={filterData.filterYears}
            onChange={setFilterYear}
            value={filterYear}
          />
          <Inputs.Select
            placeholder={t('selectFilingType')}
            list={filterData.filingTypes}
            onChange={setFilterFilingType}
            value={filterFilingType}
          />
        </InlineGroup>
      ),
      shouldShowActions: false,
    });
  };
```

when I change any values from the `select`, its values don't reflect in the modal, while they reflect when I close the modal and open it again, so it is not re-rendering, how can I make that happen? I looked up several solutions, but nothing stuck.

Comment: What is `Modal.render()`?

Comment: it is a function we wrote that renders the modal with the params I provided, same as <Modal ...props>

Comment: I suspect the issue is with that

Comment: Makes sense. Let me have a look into that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `Modal.render` sets state somewhere else. You are giving it a configuration. It is not possible to make it work like this. setting a state rerenders current react node and its children and the modal content is not in current node or its children,you are giving it what to render and it renders it somewhere else.

You can create a component that holds the state and view logic and pass it to the Modal render. This way the state will be in the modal content, not in the current node.

```
    const ModalContent = () => {
    const [filterYear, setFilterYear] = useState<string>('');
    const [filterFilingType, setFilterFilingType] = useState<string>('');
    
    return (<InlineGroup>
          <Inputs.Select
            placeholder={t('selectFilingYear')}
            list={filterData.filterYears}
            onChange={setFilterYear}
            value={filterYear}
          />
          <Inputs.Select
            placeholder={t('selectFilingType')}
            list={filterData.filingTypes}
            onChange={setFilterFilingType}
            value={filterFilingType}
          />
        </InlineGroup>)}
```

Then you can call

```
Modal.render({
  ...
  content: <ModalContent />,
  ...
});
```

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. I ultimately used a component that would have its state changes locally. Your point about this being rendered somewhere totally different is what I think the answer is.